# How to make a conjoined input with flexible width

Tags: css

I want to make a conjoined input (left-aligned text input on the same line as a right-aligned button). Something like this:

[image: example]

But it want to have flexible width (the combined inputs should stretch to 100% of the parent container width, which can be of any width. Particularly, the text input should stretch to use all available space on the line).

I tried:

- button float:right with text input width:100% **(this overflows onto 2 lines)**
- text input width: calc(100% - 90px) **(almost works, but button width varies on each browser)**

Code example with **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeobv5qy/1/)**:

HTML:

```
<div class="conjoined-input">
 <input type="button" value="Update">
 <input type="text">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.conjoined-input {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.conjoined-input input[type="text"] {
    /*width: 100%;*/
}

.conjoined-input input[type="button"] {
    float: right;
}
```

I need only modern browser support (IE9+) and can use any HTML and CSS.

How do I make a conjoined input with flexible width

Comment: If your input was 100% of the container, how are you going to fit the button on the same line? Instead of using floats, do the reverse of what you tried to do; make the button a set width, then just make the input calc(100% - buttonWidth), set them both to display inline-blocks and call it a day.

Comment: @slime how can I make the button a set width when different browsers use slightly different widths to render the button text?

Comment: What do you mean? If you set the button width/font-size...the button is going to look exactly the same on every browser.

Comment: @slime [example](http://jsfiddle.net/22n7a4h5/) - Ubuntu Firefox gives button width of 160px, Ubuntu Chrome gives button width of 123px.

Comment: If you set the width, which your example didn't do, how would they be different widths?

Comment: @slime, okay got it. Then the buttons have a different text margin in each browser, but it's a reasonable solution.

Comment: Setting the width, height, padding, and font-size will make them same across the browsers...just gotta make sure to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very easy using flex:

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yeobv5qy/14/)

[image]

```
.conjoined-input {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
}

.conjoined-input input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
}
```

IE9 is happy?

## [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/v7YTT/1933/)

[image]

so, wrap your input in a div.

```
 <button>Search</button>
 <span><input type="text" title="Search" /></span>
```

then apply the magic styles

```
.conjoined-input {
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.conjoined-input input[type="text"]{
    width: 100%
}
.conjoined-input span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right:10px;
}
.conjoined-input button{
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: ya, I forgot how `input` elements were displayed... if it were a div, it'd have been spot on... lol. check my edit.